# Applescript - get terminal window number of window where command is executed

Tags: shell, applescript, tty

I am trying to apply a command to the specific window where I run it. For example:

`osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to set the font size of window 1 to 14"`

If you have multiple windows open, this might run on the window where you run the command, or one of the other windows, depending if it's focused, not focused, on same monitor or not... I would like to replace `window 1` with something like `currentWindow`, and by this I mean, always the window where I run the script.

Comment: Is this command being run manually or part of a script? Will this be executed in a background window by a script? Also, use `osascript -e '...'` then you do not need to escape `"` within.

Comment: @user3439894 sorry, it will be executed manually from the command line

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution. My problem is a little complex, in the sense that the Applescript is running inside another script, so the window may not be front window.

Answer (score 1):

If it will always be executed manually from the command line then the following will work:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to set the font size of the front window to 14'
```

So will:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to set the font size of window 1 to 14'
```

As the `front window` is always `window 1` in this context.

Comment: when you have a script that spawns multiple terminals each trying to set their own window font, that wouldn't work because "front window" would be very random